# Trying to send serial data to computer over network from Arduino Yún

Tags: serial, arduino-yun, serial-data

Using `Console.write()` to send data to my computer over network, which works when I use the serial monitor. However, I'm using PLX-DAQ to receive Serial communication and input it into an Excel document. The problem with that is that PLX-DAQ only has the option to listen over physical ports.

Is there a workaround to this?

If it helps, the computer is a Windows machine.

Comment: Do you have the data in the ATmega32U4 (Arduino Leonardo alike part) or in the OpenWrt linux part ? If you have the data in the ATmaga32U4, then connect it to a computer via a usb cable en use the Serial functions. There are usb cables of 10 meters long and they allow even that a few are concatenated. I don't know if a Windows serial driver exists that accepts  data transmitted by Console.write(). I doubt if the Arduino Yun is reliable enough for that. You could have two Arduino boards, one connected to the computer, and communication between them with RF or UDP.

Comment: I can send the data through a USB cable, but the whole point is to send the data over a network. Also, I'd prefer not to buy any extra hardware. Thank you though.

Comment: Perhaps some kind of "serial over IP" with a virtual serial port on the computer. But I have never used something like that.